# Google Maps "copy to clipboard" via share menu

Tags: google, maps

Samsung S9+ user here.

On my old S6 I used to be able to enter a location in Google Maps, click the 'share' button, then click an option 'copy to clipboard.'  This would copy a goo.gl link to the clipboard that I could then easily paste into messages.

On the S9+ this is no longer available.  This is a problem.

I send anywhere from 50-100 text messages per day to my staff and each one has a Google Maps link... I can no longer just copy and paste this link, the only way I can do this is to 'share' the link via SMS to a random contact, cut the link, delete the excess text, then go to the staff SMS, and paste the link.  It doesn't sound like much, but over 50 messages it's A LOT of work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Copy to clipboard option only appears if you have [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs) installed. Alternatively, one can install "clipboard" apps available on Play Store for this purpose

Installing Google Drive fixed the problem as [confirmed by OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202193/google-maps-copy-to-clipboard-via-share-menu?noredirect=1#comment258550_202193)