# How to use clipboard in Galaxy A30s everywhere?

Tags: samsung, keyboard, copy-paste

When going through the options available on my keyboard, found a section which references "Clipboard".

[image]

In specific places, like in Stack Overflow's question box we can se from the opacity that's not active.

I would like the opportunity to use it anytime I wanted, not just when in particular locations like Google Keep.

Comment: I would assume that this button is only for pasting from clipboard, hence it gets active if you copy something to the clipboard. Long pressing a text section usually opens a small menu for copy to clipboard. The address bar also has a copy functionality, usually there is a special button to to so in the share menu.

Comment: @Robert I have many things copied to the clipboard (things i simply selected and clicked "copy") and that's still inactive

Comment: What keyboard app do you use? (if it is not GBoard please also provide the PlayStore link)

Comment: @Robert it's the one that comes as default in this phone, I didn't change it

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what standard keyboard app is used on your device. Depending on the manufacturer it could be any keyboard.

Comment: @Robert under "Manage keyboards" it mentions just "Samsung Keyboard"

Comment: @Robert you might be right when you state that the "Clipboard" gets active in locations it can be used. I just checked in Google Keep and it worked there; just didn't work in the browser in the way I did...

Comment: Maybe this [solution helps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202264/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams just edited the question, it was misleading but got clarified while commenting with Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've fixed it was to change the keyboard from Samsung Keyboard to Gboard and now got a Clipboard icon always active

[image]

And can use anywhere just fine

[image]